# Wipe HDD after X amount of BitLocker attempts?

Tags: windows-8, tablet, bitlocker, x86, windows-rt

I am looking for a solution to secure Windows 8 Pro (x86) tablets since Remote Wipe is only available for Windows RT (ARM) devices.

I currently have Bitlocker + PIN setup on the device and was wondering if I could have this wipe the device after say 10 attempts similar to a phone? I am open to other ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: Short-answer is no, but I asked [this](http://superuser.com/questions/540906/can-bitlocker-in-windows-7-or-8-notify-a-server-or-administrator-of-password-fai) after seeing your question- in case something round-about can be done and referenced back here as an answer.