# Can BitLocker in Windows 7 or 8 notify a server or administrator of password-failures?

Tags: security, login, remote, notifications, bitlocker

There seems to be no significant security consequences to failing login-attempts with BitLocker other than brute-force prevention.  Is there a way to have a deployment notify a server or remote user of 'tolerance'-hitting?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear I'm afraid and I can't test on the machine I have it installed on since I can't get to the Event Log.

However, I'd be surprised if something doesn't get written to the Windows Event Log.

I also note that there are a number of 3rd party apps for helping to Manage Bitlocker so you might want to investigate them.